# SpringMVC 3.2.4 Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just started working with Java and Spring, coming from a C# background and I am having trouble getting a 'PUT' request to work.

I am on Spring 3.2.4 running on Jetty 9.0.6.

I have a simple controller with the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("content-location", "/api/employees/" + id);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When this request is executed, I get the following error:

> Oct 31, 2013 10:16:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>
> WARNING: Request method 'PUT' not supported

If I change the RequestMethod to 'POST' it works fine.

Does Spring support 'PUT' requests? How do I get it to recognize the 'PUT'

Joe

**EDIT**

Turns out I was being stupid. Affe clued me in when he mentioned the url.
I was accessing it like 'api/employees?id=32' when it should have been 'api/employees/32'

In the hopes this helps someone else, here is the web descriptor, the servlet and the controller.

#### Web Descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'
         xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         xsi:schemaLocation='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd'
         version='3.0'>
    <display-name>timesheet-app</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

#### MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans'
       xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
       xmlns:context='http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd'>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package='org.timesheets.web' />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'>
        <property name='prefix' value='/WEB-INF/views/' />
        <property name='suffix' value='.jsp' />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> get() {

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            employees.add(new Employee(i, "Test " + i, "Department " + i));
        }

        return employees;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Employee get(@PathVariable Integer id) {

        return new Employee(1, "Test", "IT");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("content-location", "/api/employees/32");

        return new ResponseEntity<>("", headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("content-location", "/api/employees/" + id);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Spring MVC supports `PUT`. Please show us your servlet configuration.

Comment: @Nambari Then the request wouldn't get to Spring's servlet.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Correct, warning is from Spring container, so it might not be server level issue.

Comment: Or it's not finding that particular method in the mapping.  What is the actual full mapping and URL?

Comment: Just posted an edit containing the descriptor, servlet and controller. However, it looks like I was being stupid and @Affe clued me in on it by mentioning the url. An invalid url error message or something along those lines would have been nice. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was as @Affe pointed out that it could not find the url in the mapping because I was requesting the wrong url!

I was accessing the url like '/api/employees?id=32' instead of '/api/employees/32', though I would have thought the parameter binding would still pick it up.